# XML Schema regex to allow for a character to appear consecutively but reject if appears only once

Tags: regex, xsd

The below simpleType has a pattern value = `"[^\*]*"` , which rejects any occurrence of an asterisk in the string, which is the character we designated to blank out the corresponding database column:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="StringMin1Max80TypeBase">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
        <xsd:maxLength value="80"/>
        <xsd:pattern value="[^\*]*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Some of our simpleTypes don't have this pattern value in order to allow people to enter the `*` .  Someone recently submitted an element with the above type that has this string: `**WARNING**` , so this element was rejected unintentionally.  Is there a way to allow for consecutive characters like `**` or `***`, etc., but reject the appearance of exactly one character?  I know XML Schema regular expressions do not use negative lookbehind and negative lookahead and the characters `<` and `?` are not allowed in the pattern value.

If this is possible, how about also allowing `*string*` , i.e., multiple characters but not one?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to make sure are either no asterisks or two or more of them?  This should do it:

```
<xsd:pattern value="([^*]*\*){2,}[^*]*"/>
```

This is what I came up with for your second question, but I realized it answers your first question too.

**UPDATE:** According to the comment below, the regex also needs to match a string with no asterisks at all.  Not a problem; just add an alternative that matches one or more non-asterisk characters:

```
<xsd:pattern value="([^*]*\*){2,}[^*]*|[^*]+"/>
```

Comment: I am now being asked if we can reject exactly a sole asterisk character but accept everything else, including one asterisk that occurs within a string, e.g., *x .  So the only rejected case is a single asterisk: * .  Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like you don't have to worry about the "just one asterisk" case.  My original regex has to match at least two characters, and the alternative I just added to it doesn't match asterisks.  Will that do it for you?

Comment: thanks again, Alan.  Your solution works in regexr.com, but not in the sample XML created by XMLSpy- it rejects \*8 or 8\* when it should accept those.

Comment: Try wrapping it parentheses: `"(([^*]*\*){2,}[^*]*|[^*]+)"`.  It shouldn't be necessary IMO, but I can't find an authoritative reference to back me up.  Both regexes work correctly in RegexBuddy (XML Schema flavor) and in this [online XSD tester](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=59f15499-a00c-4202-9ec6-a227cb00e0c7-xsdvalidation).

Comment: Thanks, Alan. I might not have been clear enough, b/c your pattern does not work in the online XSD tester either, b/c it should accept *8. The only thing it should reject is . Here is my solution, which seems to work: <xsd:pattern value="((\\*)*[^\*]+(\\*)\*)*|([^\*]\*\\*){2,}"/> which allows either a string that has at least a non-asterisk character OR a string with two or more consecutive asterisks.

Comment: Sorry, but your last comment came out too garbled.  You should always use backticks (`\`...\``) to format any source code or regexes you include in your comments. That will stop special characters like backslash and asterisk being treated as markup.  More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).